# get count of records using nested has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a record A with id 1, it has_many B records which each have many C.

> A(id=1) => [b records] => [[C records for each b]]

I need to get the count of C for the given A.

I'm pretty sure there's something to to do with `joins`, groups`, or`order`, but I don't know exactly what. I need a way to do this in a constant time SQL operation. No iterative queries.

Comment: can you add some model name examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

`A.join(:b => :c).where(id: 1).count("c.id")`

If you already have an instance of `A`:

`a.b.joins(:c).count("c.id")`

Comment: Although all three of the answers give a different working solution, this one seems clearest to me.

Comment: Actually, both of these solutions need fixes.  I don't think the second solution is even possible (there is no `b` method on a).

Comment: @Swards if `a` `has_many :b` then there is a `b` method on `a`

Comment: There would probably be a `belongs_to :b` on C and a `has_many :bs` (plural) on A to distinguish between the collection and the instance

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`has_many :through` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end
```

Now you can do:

```
a.cs.count
```

If the has-many-through `a.cs` association is something you won't regularly use, and you'd rather not add it to your model, then you can use `merge` instead:

```
C.joins(:b).merge(a.bs).count
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways

```
C.joins(:b).where(:bs => {:a_id => a.id}).count
```

or

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, :through => :bs

end

# Then you can do this, nice and easy to read.  
# Use size, not count in case they are already loaded.

a.cs.size
```

or even

```
  A.where(:id => a.id).joins(:bs => :cs).count
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I had a reason not to create the has many through association for cs through bs, I would do something like:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  # has_many :cs, through: :bs - this allows a.cs.size as has been noted here
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cs
  belongs_to :a
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end


# you can always do this if you don't want to create the above association through bs:
a.bs.flat_map(&:cs).size
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Is there a question?

Comment: No question, just answering the original question with a different perspective. Trying to achieve count of A's Cs through Bs. Flat map is a different means to an end.

Comment: Sorry Jasonbuehler, I was admining questions last night and I didn't realise I'd moved into Answer admin queue to I was commenting as if a first post by a user. Sorry again.